# Convert HTML site to React importing external JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues importing external and internal JS files in React. I'm trying to convert an existing HTML website that uses JS libraries to React.

I started importing the JS. I have a Footer.js component where I import my JS files.
Footer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ImportScript from '../utils/ImportScript';

function Footer() {
  ImportScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js");
  ImportScript("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
  ImportScript("../assets/js/scripts-init/app.js");
  ImportScript("../assets/js/scripts-init/demo.js");

  // I have to return something
  return (
     <div></div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

My ImportScript helper component:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const ImportScript = resourceUrl=> {

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = resourceUrl;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [resourceUrl]);

};

export default ImportScript;
```

My App.js where I call my Footer.js. The three dots are just not related code to avoid too many code here.

```
...
import Footer from './components/Footer';
...

function App() {
   ... 
   ...
   
   return (
     <div>
       <Footer />
     </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

When I run it, I got not errors in the react terminal, but in the browser console, I got the errors:

```
The script from “http://localhost:3000/assets/js/scripts-init/app.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'  app.js
```

```
The script from “http://localhost:3000/assets/js/scripts-init/demo.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'  demo.js
```

This one says from 'util.js' I do not have a util.js file, so I assume it is from bootstrap.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: p is undefined
    <anonymous> util.js:55
    <anonymous> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
    <anonymous> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
```

I'm new with React. I'm trying to understand how it works. Btw, the some app.js and demo.js files in the HTML website, does not output any error in the browser console.

Comment: If you look in the network panel of the browser at the content of the files causing the error, you'll see (with high degree of confidence) that each of those is either the server's 404 html page or the `index.html` file from your server landing page. This is caused because your server is returning a 404 for those resources.

Comment: I'm running it localhost. In the network panel, I can see that it is loading the files.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like app.js and demo.js are react / .jsx files, and need to be compiled to javascript before they are run on browser. Now you are trying to load those directly without compilation.

Comment: app.js and demo.js are javascript files from my assets folder. I'm trying to load in the same way that I load it for HTML by <script> tags. How can I compile these files?

Comment: So they do not contain JSX/React code? (HTML in line with javascript)

Comment: Compilation depends on your project setup. What are you using to compile and bundle your react app now? If you just import those files, those will get compiled like the other JSX files.

Comment: I created a project using ```npx create-react-app my-app```. Then, I run it by ```npm start``` which triggers ```react-scripts start```

Comment: Ok. Create react app project compiles all the files it can find when starting from src/index.js by following imports. Now the demo.js and app.js are not imported normally, so create-react-app scripts don't find and compile those. What are you trying to achieve by loading them dynamically?

Comment: I'm converting a HTML website to React. These JS files are from the website assets folder. Just scripts that I need to make the website works

Comment: But that's the error message you get when the js file you are trying to run contains some tags, like a <script> tag in the beginning.

Comment: Okay. How can I import these JS files to my React project?

Comment: e.g.
import * from '../assets/js/scripts-init/demo.js';  on top of the file

Comment: I'm sorry, top of what file?

Comment: Eg. on top of the src/index.js